# Facebook Deauthorize callback not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-canvas

I have defined the Deauthorize Callback URL in the application settings. And according to the facebook documentation whenever a user removes an application, a HTTP POST request is sent containing signed_request which contains user id.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

I have tried doing the same but for some odd reason i believe that the URL specified never gets pinged on removing because i tried adding some random UPDATE query and it never got triggered.

```
 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
$user_id = $data['user_id'];
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `removeapp` (uid) VALUES ('$user_id')");
```

Comment: you are actually opening a connection to your DB above this code, right?

Comment: Yes i have already done that by including a connection file which i am doing on the other pages too!

Comment: try logging the info instead of making MySQL query: `error_log('POST Request = ' . print_r($data, true), 3, './deauthorize.log');` it's working just fine for me

Comment: I am sorry i didn't quite get how to use it? should i replace my current code and paste the one you just wrote as it is?

Comment: nevermind i think i get what this will do.. it will save the data in error_log file right? :D

Comment: yes, just create the log file, then uninstall your app to see the result.

Comment: i did that but it didn't populate anything in the error_log and it didn't make the deauthorize.log file either
`
    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
error_log('POST Request = ' . print_r($data, true), 3, './deauthorize.log');
`

Comment: to ensure i have placed the right url in the app settings i ran the file directly in the browser after copying it from there and it created the deauthorize.log file

Comment: do you have other includes? ...etc? try running the script on the browser directly with ALL errors set to show (warning, notices...etc) to see if there's something else affecting the script.

Comment: There aren't any includes or anything.. i am pasting the code i tried which didn't yield any results. This is the only content in the file


<?php
    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
 error_log('POST Request = ' . print_r($data, true), 3, './deauthorize.log');
?>

Comment: Changing the url from https to http made it work fine! Thanks alot for the help @ifaour

Comment: I had the same problem with https, and I finally figured out *why* today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369169/facebook-deauthorize-callback-over-https/20024430#20024430

Should this question or my original one be closed as a duplicate? I've already answered my own at the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

see facebook's servers are able to reach your callback URL.